# ANOVA with only one column containing numbers

Tags: statistics

I need to conduct an ANOVA, but I don't really know where to start, because in the internet I haven't found one example where there is only one column with numbers. In the picture below you can see what it looks like, so I wanted to ask how I can calculate the SST (sum of squares total) while only having one column with numbers. Thanks :)

[Anova](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbOgc.png)

Comment: Well, ANOVA is not converned with "columns containing numbers", but with samples you take under varying conditions. Try to phrase your question in terms that explain what your "columns" and "numbers" are -- quite likely, they are "conditions" and "samples". Then think about what you want the ANOVA to *test for* -- what's the question that you want answered about your data? Once you have done those things, come back and edit this question into something that can actually be answered. And you might want to consider moving this to http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one-way ANOVA has two variables, one numerical (your 'column of numbers') and the other categorical (in your case levels are denoted A, B, etc.).  This way of displaying data for an
ANOVA is sometimes called 'stacked format' because the values for all of the
groups are 'stacked' into a single column.

In the ANOVA
procedure you want to know if the groups designated by various letters differ
significantly in their numerical values.
For example, you will start by finding the sample mean ad SD of of the numbers corresponding to group A. Then for group B, and so on.